# can i use google chat api with service account and without any chat app from google console?

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-chat

can i use google chat api with service account and without any chat app from google console
i use php/Laravel with google client Library. and need to get data from chat api in my project.
and I need any google workspace accoun.
can i use this api as service account.

```
protected $apiUrl;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->apiUrl = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1';
    }

    protected function getAccessToken1()
    {
        $credentialsPath = Storage::path('credentials.json');
       
        $credentials = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);

        $jwtPayload = [
            'iss' => $credentials['client_email'],
            'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.spaces',
            'aud' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
            'exp' => time() + 3600, 
            'iat' => time()
        ];

        $jwt = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode($jwtPayload, $credentials['private_key'], 'RS256');
        $client = new Client();

        $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
                'assertion' => $jwt
            ]
        ]);

        $accessToken = json_decode($response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];
        
        if (!$accessToken) {
            return;
        }

        $url = $this->apiUrl . "/spaces";
        $headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ];
        // $body = [
        //     'text' => $messageText,
        // ];

        $response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->get($url);
        // dd($response);
        if ($response->successful()) {
            return $response;
        } else {
            $error = $response->json();
            return $error;
        }
    }
```

my code
api return that

"Google Chat app not found. To create a Chat app, you must turn on the Chat API and configure the app in the Google Cloud console.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable and configure the Chat API to make calls asynchronously. Start enable and configure flow at https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=chat.googleapis.com.

Some methods require user credentials via Oauth, see this table https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/auth#types-required